# GD library with PNG support required for image (alpha channel)

Tags: ubuntu, png, gd, mpdf

I am facing an issue in MPDF, when adding an image with transparent background in a PDF file.

`GD library with PNG support required for image (alpha channel) (b3d143b43610428bba3fcacafa40fdf6) in file: /var/www/html/myproject/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Image/ImageProcessor.php on line: 575`

**OS:** Ubuntu 22.04

**Library:** https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf

I have checked, GD library is installed and loaded in my server. This is working properly in my another Ubuntu instance

How can I fix this? Is there anything that needs to be configured to have PNG support in GD library?

Comment: Does your phpinfo say PNG Support enabled? I guess not and that means you need to compile (or install package with compiled) png support with --with-png-dir flag. https://www.php.net/manual/en/image.installation.php